# Running JS on other sites with Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to run Javascript code on other websites (with same-origin policy) using Visual Studio? When it runs, I want it to "open" the webpage (doesn't have to be opened visually) and then run the javascript code on it. The javascript code I am using needs to be able to use GET and POST requests written in jQuery.

If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same origin policy does not effect `<script>` tags, and Visual Studio is an Integrated Development Environment and also will have 0 effect on how this policy works. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to get informed about how cross domain works on the modern web.

Comment: The javascript code I am using needs to be able to use GET and POST requests written in jQuery.

Comment: The link I gave you above informs you about how that works, but basically the server that hosts the data you are getting with jQuery will need to have to have its header set to allow you to access it from your site. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ for details on the setup don't forget to accept this as your answer if it satisfied what you have asked in your question fully

Comment: But it doesn't have it's header set to allow me to access it from my site...

Comment: This http://enable-cors.org/index.html is a how to for every type of backend, but thats only if you are able to access this server

Comment: It's not my site... I don't think I can just enable CORS on it.

Comment: this is not possible.